# Regular expression for non-standard ascii characters

Tags: c#, regex

i need a regular expression that check a string for any non-standard ASCIi characters.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "non-standard"? (And for that matter, what you mean by "ASCII". Normally by "ASCII characters" people mean from 00 to 7F, but there's some variation.)

Comment: There are no "non-standard" ASCII characters. ASCII (codepoints 0x00-0x7F) is pretty well standardized. Anything at codepoint 0x80 or higher isn't ASCII, by definition

Comment: I think the sensible way to interpret the question is: non-(standard ASCII characters), not (non-standard) (ASCII characters).  Though the wording can be misinterpreted by some, I think this is a fine question.  It helped me.

Answer (score 4):

You can specify character's unicode point in c# string: `"[\u0080-\uFFFF]"` should find any character whose "ascii" code is 128+

Answer (score 1):

does this simple one suit your needs ?
[^\x20-\x7E]

Comment: I like this one best, although, I needed to add "\t\n\r" to skip some of the standard whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Put what you consider the standard characters in a set, then put the negate ^ sign in the set. That will match the nonstandard. For example I consider the standard to be a-z so my nonstandard match pattern would be

[^A-Za-z]

if that matches you have a non standard.